# How do I compute my limits of integration for a density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$ f(x,y) = 6x^2y \ $ if $0 \leq x \leq 1 , 0\leq y \leq 1$ and $0$ in other case.

How to compute $ P(X+Y>1) $ ?

$$ P(X+Y>1) = P(X>1-Y) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1-y} 6x^2y \ dx \ dy $$

Is this correct?

Comment: $f(x+y) \neq f(x,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is $\int_0^{1}\int_{1-y}^{1} 6x^{2}y dx dy$.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate out $X$ and $Y$, for your specific case  they turn out to be independent:
$$
f_X(x) = 3 x^2\\
f_Y(y) = 2y
$$
Define $Z=X+Y$, this is called convolution of rvs. To find density of $Z$, you need to solve for $y$:
$$
0<y<z: f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z}6x^2(z-x)dx  \\
z-1<y<1: f_Z(z) = \int_{z-1}^{1}6x^2(z-x)dx  \\
$$
Hence, distribution of $Z$ is
$$
f_Z(z) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\frac{z^4}{2},& 0<z<1\\
-\frac{z^4}{2}+3z^2-2z,& 1<z<2\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now, the probability $P(Z>1) = \int_{0}^{1}f_Z(z)dz = 0.9$